# Issue with Swagger (login page of the website is shown)

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I am very new to Swagger, so this may be a silly question.

I installed Swagger on my .net core 6 web app (with React installed).

Basically all of the following

- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen

Although, I know the last three should be present in the first one.

Here are my services added to program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
```

And then I have settings for the app:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = "";
});
```

and

```
app.UseSwagger(x => x.SerializeAsV2 = true);
```

When I run and go to url

```
https://localhost:44486/swagger
https://localhost:44486/swagger/index.html
```

the same content as

```
https://localhost:44486/
```

(which is the login page) shows.

Any Idea why this happens?

Comment: if you want to access swagger with url, then don't set `c.RoutePrefix = "";`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the problem:

Since I am using react and .netcore, the two services were loaded on two different ports. I had to setup ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT in my .env

Also, I had forgotten to do

```html
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```